# Code completion of not-imported "pimps" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is it possible in current IntelliJ IDEA (12) to enable code completion of "pimps" (implicit def and implicit class stuff, similar to extension methods from C#) which are not in current scope = no import statement in current file contains them.

What I'd want is similar to a not-imported class/trait/object behaviour - IDE underlines it and asks if I want to add an import statement for it. The best would be if "pimped" methods/operator would be shown in code completion list, probably from module (or some other) scope and IDE would add (or ask to include) imports automatically when this new method/operator is used.

Can this be achieved either by changing settings or by using some plugin?

EDIT1:
Sample code

`Pimps.scala`

```
object Pimps {
  implicit class stringPimps(s: String) {
    def myMethod = s"** $s **"
  }
}
```

`Main.scala`

```
import Pimps._ // without this import

object Main extends App {
  println("xxx".myMethod) // IDE won't suggest "myMethod"
}
```

Comment: Use [class name completion](http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/872/6yg.png). Shortcut can be found in your keymap.

Comment: It doesn't suggest not-imported custom "pimps".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `Alt-Ctrl-Space`, it suggests non-imported implicits too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything. Could you please write how the action is named in `settings->keymap` list? (I might have rebound it, on the other hand I wasn't able to find it on the [cheatsheet](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)...)

Comment: It is `Class name completion`. I use `VimIdea`, but in your sheatsheet the key binding is the same (at the very begin, third line).

Comment: Oh, sorry, don't know how I could missed that. But unfortunately it does not suggest not-imported methods from implicit class ("extension" method) :(. Or does something else must be enabled first?

Comment: No, I did nothing special.